# Why does this Spring application not work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have [this project](https://github.com/dptij/spring-boot-sample). Then I do the following steps:

1. `cd spring-boot-aws-spike`
2. `mvn clean compile install spring-boot:repackage`
3. `cd target`
4. `java -jar spring-boot-sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
5. Go to `http://localhost:8080/`
6. Expected result: Error message (rendered in browser)

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>   Tue Aug 27 16:59:23 CEST 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

How can I change the attached code so that instead of this error, the file [index.xhtml](https://github.com/dptij/spring-boot-sample/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml) is rendered?

**Update 1:** If I go to `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, I get this error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Aug 27 17:07:53 CEST 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Looks the same as before.

Comment: Post your controller code ,otherwise its tough to identify the issue.

Comment: @Shubh Do I need a controller to render a simple XHTML page?

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your code at the link you shared ,I mean you should post some relevant code like what you are doing to render a page in your project

Comment: http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml ?

Comment: @kaos I get the same message at the address you suggested. See update 1.

Comment: @DP_ looks like some of the code is missing like templates.. (/templates/template.xhtml)

Comment: @DP_ you are  trying to excute a `war` file with `java -jar` command. Not really sure it will work. You need to run it in a container like `Tomcat` or `Payara` etc...

Answer (score 0):

This example seems to be incomplete (some code is missing). I got this in logs after running it:

```
2019-08-27 17:19:42.119 ERROR 12588 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[facesServlet]         : Servlet.service() for servlet [facesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/file:/D:/workspace/spring-boot-sample-master/target/spring-boot-sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war*/index.xhtml @7,8 <p:> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough, but no tag was defined for name: ] with root cause

javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /file:/D:/workspace/spring-boot-sample-master/target/spring-boot-sample-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war*/index.xhtml @7,8 <p:> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough, but no tag was defined for name:
```

It works when You remove missing tag declaration from index.xhtml (still have to point directly to index -> http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <div class="row">
        Heyo!
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```